# RegEx: extract Key=Value pairs with Escape \=

Tags: regex

I have String (inside i have escaping of equal sing \=) :

```
attr1=ActiveList attr2=<Resource URI\="/All Active Lists/_CAL/Infrastructure/Active Directory/Inventory/Inventory - By User (Dedd)" ID\="DSdddCcSSS\=\="/> attr3=ActiveLis  attr4=ActiveList attr5=<Resource URI\="/All Active Lists/_CAL/Infrastructure/Active Directory/Inventory/Inventory - By User (Bobo)" ID\="CCCsSSdDDD\=\="/> attr6=ActiveLis
```

P.S. Sometimes might be:

```
key=value \= otherthink
```

How do i covert it to key=value pairs with regex:

```
attr1=ActiveList 
attr2=<Resource URI\="/All Active Lists/_CAL/Infrastructure/Active Directory/Inventory/Inventory - By User (Dedd)" ID\="DSdddCcSSS\=\="/> 
attr3=ActiveLis  
attr4=ActiveList 
attr5=<Resource URI\="/All Active Lists/_CAL/Infrastructure/Active Directory/Inventory/Inventory - By User (Bobo)" ID\="CCCsSSdDDD\=\="/>   
attr6=ActiveLis 
key=value \= otherthink
```

I'v tried few patterns eg.

```
\s?(\w+)\s?\=\s?(.(?!\=(?<!\\\=))(?!\w+\=))+
```

The target language(s): Java & Python. i prefer pure RegEx

Without success. :-\

Comment: What is the tatget language? Where will the regex be used? How are you using the regex you showed? Also, see [`\w+=(?:<([^>]*)>|(\S+))`](https://regex101.com/r/gfrGrf/3).

Comment: Do you want to extract one key-value pair per string, or do you have a string with multipl key-value pairs, and you want to extract all of them?  If it's the former, don't use a regex.  A simple `s.split('=', 1)` (in Python) should do the trick.

Comment: Why is this tagged java, javascript and python?  The question does nor reference any of the languages, so I'm removing the tags.

Comment: @VMRuiz Which is exactly what my comment is saying.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Sorry, I misread your comment.

Comment: The target language(s): Java & Python

Comment: @SvenMarnach Your right the stackoverflow interface suggested me to add Programming languages. so i tried to be good boy and add general languages. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you either have a word like `ActiveList` or something in bewteen `<>` you could is this reg exp:

`\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*(\w+|<.*?>)\s*`

First group will capture the `attr` name and second will capture a word (`ActiveList`) or anything between <> like `<Resource URI\="/All Active Lists/_CAL/Infrastructure/Active Directory/Inventory/Inventory - By User (Bobo)" ID\="CCCsSSdDDD\=\="/>`

Then, you just need to iterate over results and join them with `=`:

```
>>> for attr, value in re.findall("\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*(\w+|<.*?>)\s*",text):
        print "%s=%s" % (attr, value)

attr1=ActiveList
attr2=<Resource URI\="/All Active Lists/_CAL/Infrastructure/Active Directory/Inventory/Inventory - By User (Dedd)" ID\="DSdddCcSSS\=\="/>
attr3=ActiveLis
attr4=ActiveList
attr5=<Resource URI\="/All Active Lists/_CAL/Infrastructure/Active Directory/Inventory/Inventory - By User (Bobo)" ID\="CCCsSSdDDD\=\="/>
attr6=ActiveLis
```

Comment: 10x!!, Looks Good! but, there is some times **key=value \= otherthink**

Comment: Then you could extend the reg exp to something like `\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*(\w+|<.*?>|\w+\s*\\=\s*\w+)\s*`

Answer (score 0):

Simply split `attr[..]=`:

```
>>> splits = [c for c in re.split('(attr[\d]=)', text) if c]
>>> for y in range(0, len(splits), 2):
...     print (splits[y], splits[y+1])
... 
attr1= ActiveList 
attr2= <Resource URI\="/All Active Lists/_CAL/Infrastructure/Active Directory/Inventory/Inventory - By User (Dedd)" ID\="DSdddCcSSS\=\="/> 
attr3= ActiveLis  
attr4= ActiveList 
attr5= <Resource URI\="/All Active Lists/_CAL/Infrastructure/Active Directory/Inventory/Inventory - By User (Bobo)" ID\="CCCsSSdDDD\=\="/> 
attr6= ActiveList
```