# RegEx: Muliple Key=Value with escaping

Tags: regex

I need help to make Key-Value parser.

Thanks to mr. @VMRuiz in post [RegEx: extract Key=Value pairs with Escape \=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43845265/regex-extract-key-value-pairs-with-escape)
he suggested this RegEx:

```
\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*(\w+|<.*?>|\w+\s*\\=\s*\w+)\s*
```

But i found few scenarios that don't work:
should help, but there was few scenarios that don't work with that regex:

```
app=tcp/444
# Catchs only Key:app Value:tcp > should catch Key:app Value:tcp/444 

catdt=Network-based 
# Current result: 
#   catdt:'Network'
#   
# Shoud be:
#   catdt:'Network-based' 

eventId=123123 externalId=11111
# Current result:
#   eventId:'123123 externalId=11111'
#
# Should catch
#  eventId: '123123'
#  externalId: '111111'

src=2.3.4.5
# Current result:
#   src:'2'
#
# Should catch
#  src: '2.3.4.5'

eventAnnotationEndTime=1493293598\=aaa00
# Should be:
#   eventAnnotationEndTime: '1493293598\=aaa00'

eventAnnotationEndTimeA=1493293598A\=aaa01 eventAnnotationEndTimeB=1493293598\=aaa02
# Should be:
#   eventAnnotationEndTimeA: '1493293598\=aaa01'
#   eventAnnotationEndTimeB: '1493293598\=aaa02'


sourceTranslatedZoneURI=/All Zones/ArcSight System/Private Address Space Zones/RFC1918: 172.3.0.0-172.3.255.255
# Should be:
#   ourceTranslatedZoneURI: '/All Zones/ArcSight System'
```

Some times i have `\=` that should escape that is not key value (see example)
Some times i have few KeyValue pairs on same line

The stub scenario list that i need extract key-value pairs:

```
eventId=47539272657 externalId=19260037
mrt=124412421
app=tcp/444
proto=TCP
in=51485
out=3125
catdt=Network-based 
modelConfidence=0
severity=0 relevance=10 assetCriticality=0
priority=3
art=124
cat=traffic:forward
deviceSeverity=3
rt=234124
shost=bzq-194et
src=1.1.1.227
sourceZoneID=Mokee5CcBABCGKZ5Updd27g\=\=
sourceZoneURI=/All Zones/ArcSight System/Public Address Space Zones/RIPE NCC/193.0.0.0-195.255.255.255 (RIPE NCC)
sourceTranslatedAddress=12.6.4.5
sourceTranslatedZoneID=Mbp432AABABCDUVpYAT3UdQ\=\=
sourceTranslatedZoneURI=/All Zones/ArcSight System/Private Address Space Zones/RFC1918: 172.3.0.0-172.3.255.255
sourceTranslatedZoneExternalID=RFC1918: 172.3.0.0-172.3.255.255
spt=17743
sourceTranslatedPort=87878
dst=1.1.3.5
destinationZoneID=Mbp432AABABCDUVp77YAT3UdQ\=\=
destinationZoneURI=/All Zones/ArcSight System/Private Address Space Zones/RFC1918: 172.3.0.0-172.31.3.255
destinationZoneExternalID=RFC1918: 172.16.0.0-172.31.255.255
dpt=444
cs1=forward
cs5=close
locality=1
cs1Label=SubType
cs2Label=Attribute
cs3Label=User
cs4Label=Path
cs5Label=Action
ahost=arc-77
agt=1.3.4.3
av=5.3.5.5973.0
atz=Asia/778
aid=DvLMkV77rYkaWDEA\=\=
at=sup7nt
dvchost=FWAZURE-B
dtz=Asia/778
deviceInboundInterface=port1
deviceOutboundInterface=port2
eventAnnotationStageID=R9MHiNfoAAxxcBCASAsxbPIxG0g\=\=
eventAnnotationStageURI=/All Stages/Queued
eventAnnotationStageUpdateTime=123123123
eventAnnotationModificationTime=11123123
eventAnnotationAuditTrail=1,1491s9,root,Queued,,,,\n
eventAnnotationVersion=1
eventAnnotationEventId=44423124
eventAnnotationFlags=0
eventAnnotationEndTime=1212312
eventAnnotationManagerReceiptTime=32323532
_cefVer=0.1 ad.
arcSightEventPath=3xZdnIloBABDH14iZHcPHvw\=\=
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might be what you look for:

```
\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*((?:\\.|[\w.,\/:()-]|\s(?!\w+\s*=))*)
```

It matches/captures the key and matches the following `=`. Then it captures -

- an escaped character (`\` followed by any character), or...
- any of the characters in the class, or finally...
- a space, **not** followed by what could be a new key.

(You haven't tagged regex flavor/language, so I'm assuming PCRE-compatible)

It doesn't handle "comments", so those would have to be filtered away first.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9P77Vb/1).

Comment: Works great except if key contains hyphen but if it's not required then it's ok !

Comment: To allow hyphen in key, change to `\s*([\w-]+)\s*=\s*((?:\\.|[\w.,\/:()-]|\s(?![\w-]+\s*=))*)`

Comment: @ClasG Thanks!!!  i'v added extra chars like <, >, .   `\s*([\w\.-]+)\s*=\s*((?:\\.|[\w.,\/:()\"\+-]|<|>|\||\s(?![\w\.-]+\s*=))*)` use case field name like a.b=value

Comment: To simplify: `\s*([\w.-]+)\s*=\s*((?:\\.|[\w.,\/:()\"\+<>|-]|\s(?![\w.-]+\s*=))*)`. 1. `.` don't need escape inside a character class, 2. add extra characters inside class instead of as alternations (better readability, quicker).

Comment: I Agree! `\s*([\w.-]+)\s*=\s*((?:\\.|[^\s]|\s(?![\w‌​\.-]+\s*=))*)` - bit more shorter

Answer (score 0):

This one should work : `^(?P<KEY>[^=#\s]+)=(?P<VALUE>.*)$`

Or without named groups : `^([^=#\s]+)=(.*)$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BfSy1d/3)

Comment: That won't handle multiple key/values on a single line.